# .Net Microsoft team Meeting API generating access denied token

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, api, microsoft-teams

I have tried to create a Microsoft team API to create an online meeting. I have created an app register in azure with clientId and tenantId. I added permission with the delegate, and in other times in public as a trial as I know delegate is the correct and then create secret, and I tested it in Microsoft explorer it works perfectly now I tried to work with it in c# code I got token. However, I noticed that the token is different from Microsoft explorer, so I got an error in creating event access denied as the token does not have permission.
The second question can I generate a unique link for the meeting for each attendance.

The error I'm receiving is

```html
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-12-03T13:05:33",
            "request-id": "cc2dbedc-610e-4d95-a30d-672ff241efa4",
            "client-request-id": "cc2dbedc-610e-4d95-a30d-672ff241efa4"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code here

Comment: Which auth flow did you use? And is there any error or post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because Security Defaults is enabled for your tenant.

Answer (score 0):

For each request made to the API, the token changes so the token received in graph explorer will be different from the token received via Code.

Check and try with [Auth Request for token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token) and pass the token received to the [online meeting API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)

Comment: Thank you @Malliprya-msft. The error I'm receiving is 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-12-03T13:05:33",
            "request-id": "cc2dbedc-610e-4d95-a30d-672ff241efa4",
            "client-request-id": "cc2dbedc-610e-4d95-a30d-672ff241efa4"
        }
    }
}

Comment: The error response is clear that you or logged on user dont have necessary permissions/scopes/roles to perform the operation(API call), hence its failing. Have you validated this at your end for the above user? I would suggest you to test it with POSTMAN (instead of Microsoft Graph Explorer_, setup the exact auth flow that you use with your app, try repro the issue, with the same

Comment: To answer your second question, i would say that i havent came across a way from API exists that you can create unique link every time.